# Couldn't run my prgram by clicking play button

Tags: java, graphics

Error: Main method not found in class gameframe.GameFrame, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

This above messages have been showing when I used to run my program by clicking play button in Netbeans IDE. But if I go to Run menu and click run file (Shift+F6) then it is running well. Any possible solution is welcomed and highly appreciated. In addition, my program is firstly done in eclipse and then copied it to Netbeans. 
Thank you

Comment: does the class ever has a main method??

Comment: Ya obviously. It has main method. That's why it can run when I click run file from file menu. but could not run by clicking play button. –

Answer (score 0):

The file you're running does not contain a main method.  Make sure that you have a main method as `public static void main(String[] args)`.  It's either that or you're not running the right class.

Make sure that when you are pressing the play button, you have the class with the main method in it.  Otherwise, it won't be able to find it.

Comment: It has main method. That's why it can run when I click run file from file menu. but could not run by clicking play button.

Comment: @HMShahriar You're positive that you're runninf the right project?  It may sound like a stupid question but it's happened to me before when I ran the wrong project because I didn't make sure that I was running the project I wanted.  Can you right click the project in the hierarchy and use "Run as" from there?

Comment: Not solved. Whenever I go to run menu and select run file(shift+f6) it runs. In any other ways it is not running.